# Google Analytics appending code to site whenever a link is clicked

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I have a website on which I have integrated the GA code. When the user clicks on the phone number and the email ID in the footer, the following string is added to the body before the `</body>` tag:

```
;window.lintrk('track', { conversion_id: XXXXXXX1 });window.lintrk('track', { conversion_id: XXXXXX7 });
```

This is repeating whenever the user clicks on the footer section.

I was able to disable the issue by removing the phone number and the email from the footer, the issue with the phone number was removed by replacing the space with no space charater (‎ ). Is there any solution to this?

I want to get a method to hide the `‎window.lintrk('track', { conversion_id: XXXXXXX1 });window.lintrk('track', { conversion_id: XXXXXX7 });` from the website.

I have used WordPress for development.

Comment: How are you initialising GA in your page? Are you saying those JS snippets are being added as text? They should be added within `<script>` tags when the page is loaded - that is the normal behaviour.

Comment: Hi I have added the script tag in the head and no script tag in the beging of the body tag.

Answer (score 0):

That seems to me like some awkward linkedin conversion pixel doing things nobody asked it to do. Shouldn't be related to Google.

Check your GTM for linkedin tags, try isolating the code that causes it. Most likely some junior has a custom HTML snippet that just gets thrown into the DOM on certain clicks.